# View returning user as None

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, email-verification

So, I'm creating a user confirmation system where a code is created, stored in the session and send through email

I made some prints inside the view that is used to confirm the code and active the user, the code is this one:

```
def activeThroughCode(request,):
    form = VerificationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VerificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            entered_code = request.POST.get('verification_code')

            stored_code = request.session.get('verification_code')
            
            print("Entered Code:", entered_code)
            print("Stored Code:", stored_code)

            username = User.objects.get('username')

            if entered_code == stored_code:
                print(username)
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                    user.is_active = True
                    user.save()
                    messages.success(request, f'Your account is active with success.')
                    return redirect('login')
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, 'Incorrect verification code.')
                    return redirect('login')

               
            else:
                messages.error(request, f"It wasn't possible to confirm your email")

    return render(request, 'activate.html',{'form': form})
```

When digiting the code in my form, I can confirm through terminal the entered code and stored code are the same, and everything is ok until here

but, for validating my user, I need, obviously, request the user to active and save it, but the result for

```
 username = User.objects.get('username')

            if entered_code == stored_code:
                print(username)
```

is None.

I'm 99% sure it's the only error, because my Exception is being printed to me, so it means the code confirmation is actually working

my forms:

```
class   MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class VerificationForm(forms.Form):
    verification_code = forms.CharField(label='Verification Code', max_length=10)
```

any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: have you checked the type of the values compared ?

Comment: you mean entered_code == stored_code ? it's all ok. The error is requesting the user. Chat GPT said about using user id for this and some stuff with pk but I didn't understand well how to apply it. I just know I need my activation template to request the user.

Comment: I'm more surprised that `username = User.objects.get('username')` doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: It only returns None. I can't save the user if I can't get his username, email or whatever. I'm trying something with id but I'm getting error from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

**If you obtain some values from your database. At that time, write this line**

*model  = User*

get *username from to database*

```
user  =  User.objects.get(username =username)
```

**in your case**

```
 user = User.objects.get(username)--->> that is wrong
```

**and**

```
form.is_valid():-->write like this
```

Comment: 'username' is not defined. that''s what vs code shows me

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug on line 5:

```
if form.is_valid:
```

This will always return `True`, because it just check the method exists. It should be a call of the method instead:

```
if form.is_valid():
```